# How can I ensure that a travis build is triggered for a particular script only when changes are made to the folder containing that script

Tags: bash, docker, travis-ci, devops

So in my repo, I have 3 individual scripts. Script A, Script B, and Script C. Each script is in respective folders A, B, C.
I want to configure my .travis.yml file in such a way that script A runs, only when there is a change in Folder A. OR Script A, and B run, when there are changes in folder A, and B.

So are there any travis hooks which I can setup on folders?

Edit:

Below is my script:

```
language: node_js

node_js: 8.12.0

group: bluezone

services:
  - docker

build_artifacts_service:
  before_install:
    - chmod +x services/artifacts- 
  service/unit_tests/deployment/controller_test.js
    - chmod +x services/artifacts- 
  service/unit_tests/driver/controller_test.js
    - cd services/artifacts-service/

  install:
    - npm install

  script:
    - npm test

  after_success:
    - bash builddocker.sh

  only:
      changes:
        - services/artifacts-service/

build_some_other_service:
  before_install:
    - echo "I was executed"

   only:
     changes:
       - images/endor/
```

It does not understand the .travis.yml file and starts installing ruby

It show this in the Travis config

```
{
  "language": "ruby",
  "os": "linux",
  "group": "stable",
  "dist": "precise"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have each of these scripts run as a different target, and have an only-changes block for it:

```
build_a:
  script:
    - ./script_a
  only:
    changes:
      - ./script_a
      - ./folder_a
```

Comment: Can you point me to an example of it. I can't find it on the internet. I need to see a couple of examples before I can write mine.

Comment: I updated the question with my travis file and the error I am getting.

Comment: Hello. Any asnwer for my question which I edited above?